# How can I merge multiple overlapping date ranges and create new ones?

Tags: algorithm, datetime, go, date-range, dateinterval

I have multiple date ranges each with a start and end date/time, containing a single value from which I want to create new ranges, where the overlapping range values are appended to a slice.

Date/time Ranges are the following:

1. [10:00, 10:15] = 7
2. [10:10, 10:20] = 9
3. [10:05, 10:25] = 2
4. [11:00, now] = 3

To illustrate it better please see the following image (I used only times here, to simplify it):

[image]

On the image a date range [10:00, 10:15] contains the value 7, [10:10, 10:20] = 9 and so on.

I would need to generate the following date ranges, where overlapping range values gets merged together:

1. [10:00, 10:05] = 7
2. [10:05, 10:10] = 7,2
3. [10:10, 10:15] = 7,2,9
4. [10:15, 10:20] = 2,9
5. [10:20, 10:25] = 2
6. [10:25, 11:00] = 2 <-- this was a gap, no overlap and not continuous.
7. [11:00, now] = 3

I used a struct to represent a range

```
type Range struct {
     Start  time.Time
     End    time.Time
     Values []int
}
```

Is there an easy and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I think you will need to write your own algo for this. 
This type of algos, in general start sorting the ranges by the first value of the tuples, and traversing them stacking them in a stack and analysing intersection and generating the new ones (you can keep also in a stack if you need to then pop and compute something on them)
check this for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/
Or any range datetime series. I remember using a B-Tree for writing an algo for merging datetime series in Database.

Comment: I know it's more of an algo problem, i posted it if anybody could help me

Comment: sorry I posted that silly frist sentence without finishing my idea :)

Comment: @Luchux no problem :)

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can show here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch of an algorithm to do this:

The data struct would be:

```
type Boundary struct {
   Time time.Time
   AddRemove int
   Value int
}
```

A `Boundary` would represent a `Value` added or removed from the list of values at a given time. For a range:

```
[from,to]=number
```

you create two `Boundary` objects:

```
b1:=Boundary{Time:from,AddRemove: 1, Value: number}
b2:=Boundary{Time:to,AddRemove:-1,Value:number}
```

You can then sort all boundary objects by time and `AddRemove`. If times are equal, you should process adds first, then removes. Once this is done, you can process the boundary objects, and create your ranges:

```
last:=time.Time{}
values:=map[int]struct{}{}
for _,b:=range boundaries {
   if last.IsZero() {
      last=b.Time
      values[b.Value]=struct{}{}
   } else {
      // Create a new range here with [last,b.Time] with values given in `values`
      if b.AddRemove==1 {
        values[b.Value]=struct{}{}
      } else {
        delete(values,b.Value)
      }
      last=b.Time
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the values map is always empty, see: https://play.golang.org/p/1xtBT5oxiHB

Or maybe I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: You should create and store your new ranges where the comment says `Create a new...`. See this: https://play.golang.org/p/wEVmM-BZCtO

Comment: In your example at line 38, the Printf you added, the new range gives the wrong start time, it's always 10:00, the end time is good, so it's [10:00, 10:10] = 7, [10:00, 10:15] = 7,9 and. [10:00, 10:20] = 9

It should be [10:00, 10:10] = 7, [10:10, 10:15] = 7,9 and [10:15, 10:20] = 9

Comment: Fixed. Add the `last=b.Time` pls.